# Connecting to XMPP Server from Android

Tags: android, xmpp

This could be duplicate question.

I am using `org.jivesoftware.smack` for android to connect as XMPP client. And my code is

```
ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
try {
    connection.connect();
    connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
    connection.sendPacket(presence);
    setConnection(connection);
} catch (XMPPException ex) {    
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'am getting an exception as below

```
01-18 16:20:36.021: W/System.err(13651): No response from the server.: 
01-18 16:20:36.021: W/System.err(13651):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.bindResourceAndEstablishSession(SASLAuthentication.java:307)
01-18 16:20:36.029: W/System.err(13651):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:214)
01-18 16:20:36.029: W/System.err(13651):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:341)
01-18 16:20:36.029: W/System.err(13651):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:301)
01-18 16:20:36.029: W/System.err(13651):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:283)
01-18 16:20:36.029: W/System.err(13651):    at com.example.chatsample.XMPPClient.setupConnection(XMPPClient.java:112)
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to connect to a Local XMPP server from an Android XMPP client. You need the following:

- Proper Asmack Jar - download [here](http://asmack.freakempire.de/)
- Proper arguments to ConnectionConfiguration - Host, Port & server
- Proper login details

ConnectionConfiguration conConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host,port, service);

- Host: If you are using local WIFI on both Android device & on your computer with XMPP server installed. You must use you LOCAL Wireless IP Address for the host. Note: NOT Ethernet IP & NOT External IP address.
- Port will remain 5222
- Server will be the server instance you created while installing your XMPP server.

**Note**: Make sure the server is started when you are trying to connect.

If you pass correct arguments to ConnectionConfiguration, you will be able to connect as follows:

XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig); 
 connection.connect();

Ones connected, you can login as a user:

connection.login(username, password);

**Note**: username need not have the server name. It can simply be **admin** etc

If you are trying to send a message to another user using something like:

Message msg = new Message(receiverUserID, Message.Type.chat);
                msg.setBody(text);
                connection.sendPacket(msg);

Make sure that receiverUserID has the @serverInstanceName as a suffix to the user ID like user2@serverInstanceName.

**Note**: I used [Ejabberd 2.1.11](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/archive/)

**TIP**: A detailed explanation of how to create an Android XMPP Client and how to connect to a local XMPP server is provided at this [link](http://im-a-developer-too.blogspot.ca/2014/04/creating-android-xmpp-client-using.html) with complete [source code](https://github.com/gudigundla/AndroidXMPPClient).

Answer (score 1):

```
use this code for making connection with xmmp


 public static final String HOST = "talk.google.com";
    public static final int PORT = 5222;
    public static final String SERVICE = "gmail.com";


public void connect() {



        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Create a connection
                ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(HOST, PORT, SERVICE);
                XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

                try {
                    connection.connect();
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity",
                            "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to connect to "+ connection.getHost());
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }
                try {
                    // SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
                    connection.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                    Log.i("XMPPChatDemoActivity","Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

                    // Set the status to available
                    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
                    connection.sendPacket(presence);
                    setConnection(connection);

                    if(connection.isConnected())
                    {


                    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
                    Collection<RosterEntry> entries = roster.getEntries();
                    int i=0;
                    for (RosterEntry entry : entries) 
                    {

                        Presence entryPresence = roster.getPresence(entry.getUser());
                        String presenceType=entryPresence.getType().toString();



                        Presence.Type type = entryPresence.getType();                       

                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity","Type: " + entry.getType());
                        entry.getType();
                        entryPresence.getStatus();
                        entryPresence.getType();
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Status: "+ entryPresence.getStatus());
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence Type: "+ entryPresence.getType());
                        if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence AVIALABLE");
                        Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Presence : "+ entryPresence);                   

                        if (type == Presence.Type.available)
                        {
                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity","--------------------------------------");
                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity","online user Name: " + entry.getName());
                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity","online user Name: " + entry.getUser());

                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity","--------------------------------------");

                            onlineuseremail.add(entry.getUser());
                            onlineuserlist.add(entry.getUser());

                            Log.d("XMPPChatDemoActivity","--------------------emaill------------"+onlineuseremail.get(i++));


                        }

                    }   
                    }

                } catch (XMPPException ex) {
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", "Failed to log in as "+ USERNAME);
                    Log.e("XMPPChatDemoActivity", ex.toString());
                    setConnection(null);
                }

                //              dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        t.start();

    }
```

Comment: First am unable to connect. The code looks same and its working for gmail accounts.

But I have a server running at 1xx.1xx.x.x port on port 5222. I would like to connect to that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use to connect to my XMPP server (in ejabberd).

```
//...
    SmackAndroid.init(context);
    AndroidConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new AndroidConnectionConfiguration(ip_server, 5222,ip_server);

    connectionConfiguration.setReconnectionAllowed(true);
    connectionConfiguration.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
    connectionConfiguration.setCompressionEnabled(true);
    connectionConfiguration.setSecurityMode(SecurityMode.required);
    connectionConfiguration.setTruststoreType("AndroidCAStore");
    connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePassword(null);
    connectionConfiguration.setTruststorePath(null);

    mConnection = new XMPPConnection(connectionConfiguration);

    mConnection.connect();

    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mConnection.login(user, pass,"SMACK-"+telephonyManager.getDeviceId());
//...
```

Hope it helps